# Twitter Bootstrap v2.3.2 Responsive menu not working in IE or Safari, or mobile

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-2

I used this version of Bootstrap just a few months ago to create another site, and I could have SWORN I tested it in IE and Safari, and on my Samsung Galaxy S3 - at any rate, the responsive menu is only working in Chrome and FF.  Started a new site today using this version of Bootstrap (2.3.2) and realized, nope, it isn't working.

http://byd1.us/Seagrove/index.php

When you resize the browser window the menu won't change from the normal, full screen menu to the drop down button.

I KNOW this specific site is not finished.. just wanted to see if I could get this resolved first. :-(

I looked on here at about a half dozen questions similar to mine but so far none of the advice helped  (checked the headers, put the JS scripts above the closing head tag, etc).

Answer (score 0):

check these all scripts are included are not?

```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
   <![endif]-->

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

 <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

best solution is to use bootstrap 3 it will work fine, it good to upgrade so it will work fine on mobiles, when i got the problem with bootstrap 2.x version, i was just use bootstrap3

Comment: Well I went back to Bootstraps website and downloaded a fresh version of 2.3.2 - and I've got it working on my computer the way I want it to in Chrome, Safari, FF and IE.